# Sitecore security: how can I allow a role to manage certain domains?

Tags: security, sitecore, user-roles

in a Sitecore 7 build I have multiple domains but would like a user of particular role to manage users in a limited set of domains. In other words, I want all users in a role "Editor" to be able to create and edit users in domains "cms" and "web". How can this be achieved? There are no particular limitations to whether these domains have to be locally or globally managed. The problem is that if I set the required domains to be globally managed then Editor user can see too many domains, otherwise they only see the locally managed domain they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post I wrote that might help. After setting domains to locally managed you can assign which domains each user has access to if you are an admin.

http://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/how-to-use-locally-managed-domains-in-sitecore/

Unfortunately it seems like you can only do this on a per user basis and not at the role level which seems odd considering Sitecore is always adamant about working with roles instead of users.

Comment: I can do this programmically now (with help from Sitecore), but it is a custom solution and is a bit hacky.